# Purpose of the reduplication in 一步一步地往上爬

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, measure-word

（A）别着急，`一步一步`地往上爬，爬不动的时候就休息一会儿。

（B）我请田芳`一句一句`地给我纠正。

I learned about the reduplication of Measure words (e.g:个个，天天  ) but these sentences use a different structure.

（1）What is the purpose of this reduplication? Can I write "一步步" or "步步"?

（2）Is the meaning of `一个一个` different from `一个个`, `个个`?

（3）Can all classifiers use this structure "一...一..."?

Comment: If you come from an English-speaking background, personally I'm not quite sure why (1) needs explanation. `Don't worry, make the climb step-by-step, if you run out of energy you can take a break`, `I've requested 田芳 to correct me sentence-by-sentence`. What does `step-by-step` and `sentence-by-sentence` mean? Why do you need to say `step` and `sentence` twice?

Comment: There really should be just one question per question.  There's actually a close reason for multi-question questions: *This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.*  [It inhibits future users who have one of those questions, for identifying duplicates, and creating precise answers.]  If you have multiple questions, it's best to ask the most central one (showing your current level of understanding), and if you have further questions afterwards, it's fine to ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

What dROOOze wrote is correct.  一步一步 is like step by step in English.  It can be shortened as 一步步，but it will lose the cadence and some effect.

You can probably apply this structure for every measure word, e. g.  一个一个，一升一升，一条一条，etc.

Well, unlike 一个个 or 一个一个,  个个 denotes the sense of *every*.  E. g.  我们班同学个个学习好 // Every student in our class studies well.